# Filling between two lines with Matplotlib with 2 restrictions

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to fill the area between the curve y1=x^3 and then line y2=3x-2.
Below is code I have that will do this, however,  I want to place the restriction that y1 < y2 (which I have done with the where option of fill_between) and that x<1.

The problem that occurs with the code below is that the area between the curve is filled for x>1. I would like to plot these graphs on the range [-2.5,2.5]. How do I get matplotlib to stop filling between the curves for x>1?

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-2.5, 2.5, 100)
y1 = np.array([i**3 for i in x]) 
y2 = np.array([3*i-2 for i in x]) 

fig = plot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(x, y1, label=r"$y=x^3$")
ax.plot(x, y2, label=r"$y=3x-2$")
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.fill_between(x, y1, y2, where=y2<y1, facecolor='green')
ax.legend()

plot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The easiest fix is to define 3 new variables, u,v, and w, where u holds the x values for v and w, and v = x^3, w=3x-2.

```
u=x[x<1]
v=y1[y1<1]
w=y2[y2<1]
```

Then plot these values with fill_between:

```
ax.fill_between(u, v, w, where=w<v, facecolor='green')
```